# how to retrieve an instance of kendo scheduler in MVC and add a new property to this

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

i have used kendo scheduler like this

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<myEntity>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Date(currentDateTime)
    //.Events(e => { e.Error("error_handler");  })
    );
```

now i want to retrieve the same instance and add another property to it  say Events
as in

```
       .Events(e => { e.Error("error_handler");  })
```

dynamically. how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in JavaScript (only):

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data('kendoScheduler');
scheduler.bind("error", error_handler);
```

If you wanna set not event property you should find correct method to do it in kendo [documentation and api reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#events-add)

There is also `.setOptons('name', value)` method in most of kendo components but unfortunately it usually just change value of property and does not render comonent again with new options.

Comment: Thank you so much, actually i want to attach two different templates in editTemplate. i have 2 entries in scheduler first is program second is seminar.if i click on seminar only description should get open but if i click on program it should get edit.  can you suggest me the way

Comment: I've never use scheduler but this sould do: `@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<myEntity>().Name("seminar").Date(currentDateTime).Editable(false));`

Comment: thank you for your help. This will not do what i am looking for